# Minifilter to detect block-level or disk-level changes made to a file?

Tags: file, filesystems, driver, minifilter, filter-driver

I'm trying to develop a File System Minifilter driver to intercept I/O operations and determine the disk level changes made to a particular file. I found some sample code in Windows driver samples document https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/ .

This is my requirement: Each time a write operation occurs on a particular file, I need to filter it and find out what are the disk-level changes to the file this write operation makes. But I'm not sure which I/O operation I should filter for my requirement. Please point me in the right direction. I'm doing this for incremental backup purpose.

Answer (score 0):

if you interesting in disk-level changes you need look only for FLTFL_CALLBACK_DATA_IRP_OPERATION with IrpFlags & IRP_NOCACHE

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate?

Comment: disk-level changes never done in fast-io - so you need look only for FLTFL_CALLBACK_DATA_IRP_OPERATION operations. then need look for Irp flags, only if IRP_NOCACHE - will be disk-level changes. so you need filter requests in PreWrite callback by this two criteria